# How to remove values in a column based on other column values equaling the column values above it?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am currently coding in R and merged two dataframes together so I could include all the information together but I don't want the one column "Cost" to be duplicated multiple times (it was due to the unique values of the last 3 columns). I want it to include the cost 100 only in the first column and then for every other instance where the columns "State", "Market", "Date", and "Cost" are the same as above. I attached what the dataframe looks like and what I want it to be changed to. Thank you!

What it currently looks like
[image: What it currently looks like]

What it should look like
[image: What it should look like]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 3):

Please use index like in this example:

```
name_of_your_dataset[nrow_init:nrow_fin, ncol] <- NA
```

In your case, assuming the name of your dataset as 'data'

```
data[2:4,4]<- NA
```

Just leave a positive feedback and if I was useful, just vote this answer up.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using duplicated with your dataframe (df)

```
     State  Market    Date Cost    Word format               Type
1    AZ Phoenix 10-20-2020  100   HELLO     AM     Sports related
2    AZ Phoenix 10-21-2020   NA GOODBYE     PM Non Sports related
3    AZ Phoenix 10-22-2020   NA     YES     FM            Country
4    AZ Phoenix 10-23-2020   NA    NONE     CM               Rock
```

Set duplicates to NA

```
df$Cost[duplicated(df$Cost)] <- NA
```

Output:

```
  State  Market       Date Cost    Word format               Type
1    AZ Phoenix 10-20-2020  100   HELLO     AM     Sports related
2    AZ Phoenix 10-21-2020   NA GOODBYE     PM Non Sports related
3    AZ Phoenix 10-22-2020   NA     YES     FM            Country
4    AZ Phoenix 10-23-2020   NA    NONE     CM               Rock
```

Answer (score 1):

The column `Date` is different so I think you want to do replace duplicated `Cost` for every value of `State` and `Market` combination.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(State, Market) %>%
  mutate(Cost = replace(Cost, duplicated(Cost), NA)) %>%
  ungroup

df

#  State Market  Date        Cost Word    format Type              
#  <chr> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>             
#1 AZ    Phoenix 10-20-2020   100 HELLO   AM     Sports related    
#2 AZ    Phoenix 10-21-2020    NA GOODBYE PM     Non Sports related
#3 AZ    Phoenix 10-22-2020    NA YES     FM     Country           
#4 AZ    Phoenix 10-23-2020    NA NONE    CM     Rock
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(State = c("AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ"), Market = c("Phoenix", 
"Phoenix", "Phoenix", "Phoenix"), Date = c("10-20-2020", "10-21-2020", 
"10-22-2020", "10-23-2020"), Cost = c(100, 100, 100, 100), Word = c("HELLO", 
"GOODBYE", "YES", "NONE"), format = c("AM", "PM", "FM", "CM"), 
    Type = c("Sports related", "Non Sports related", "Country", 
    "Rock")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```